# Function to find object type in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to know if there is any ruby function or method to find out the type of object (`Integer`, `String`, `Symbol`, etc.).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The assumption you've made is that if the value returned by a mathematical operation is an integer, the value's class will be Fixnum. That's not correct.

Take a look:

```
a = 5
puts a.class
# => Fixnum

b = 5.0
puts b.class
# => Float
```

Mathematically speaking, 5 and 5.0 are the same number and that number is an integer. But 5 and 5.0 in Ruby (like many other programming languages) are not the same. One is a [fixed-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) value (ergo Fixnum) and the other is a [floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) value (Float). A Fixnum can represent integers only, but a Float can represent both integers and fractions (but, it behooves me to mention, [not all fractions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)).

In Ruby, when you do a mathematical operation with two Fixnums, a Fixnum is returned:

```
a = 4
puts a.class # => Fixnum

x = a ** 2
puts x       # => 16
puts x.class # => Fixnum
```

However, if either number is a Float, a Float is returned:

```
a = 4

x = a ** 2.0
puts x       # => 16.0
puts x.class # => Float

b = 4.0
puts b.class # => Float

y = b ** 2
puts y       # => 16.0
puts y.class # => Float

y = b ** 2.0
puts y       # => 16.0
puts y.class # => Float
```

You asked how to "find the type of an object," and the answer to that question is to use the [`Object#class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-class) method, as above. But as you can see, "Is the object a Fixnum?" and "Is the object an integer?" are two different questions.

If you want to know if a number in Ruby is an integer even if it's a Float, refer to the excellent answers to this question: [Checking if a Float is equivalent to an integer value in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083202/checking-if-a-float-is-equivalent-to-an-integer-value-in-ruby)

Answer (score 8):

You could call `class method` on object

```
obj.class
```

For Instances

```
:test_1.class => Symbol
```

---

Or you could also Used: [`instance_of? Method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_of-3F)

```
puts 10.instance_of? Fixnum    #=> True
puts [1,2].instance_of? Array  #=> True
```

for more Info you could [determining-type-of-an-object-in-ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769739/determining-type-of-an-object-in-ruby) see this

Answer (score -1):

`42` is an instance of `Fixnum`, `Fixnum` is a subclass of `Numeric`.
`4.2` is an instance of `Float`, `Float` is a subclass of `Numeric` as well.

```
42.kind_of? Numeric
=> true

(4.2).kind_of Numeric
=> true
```